# How can we Validate Credit Card Numbers with White Spaces using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, validation

I would like to know how can we validate the Credit Card.

We have a script that allows the numbers like this

```
4444111122223333
```

I want the credit card validation to accept credit card number in this format (with white spaces.)

```
4444 1111 2222 3333
```

How it can be possible in JavaScript.

Thanks

A

Comment: are you using any framework? such as jquery? if so, have a look at [some validation plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Comment: you don't need a framework. you just need to know the algorithm that makes a card number a valid card number (card numbers aren't like IDs that are "auto increment")

Comment: Actually, we are using Jquery. but we are not focusing on the Credit Card types like Amex, Citibank, etc. etc. At the moment we are just focus on the validation with White spaces.

Comment: All you need to do is remove the spaces and pass it to your current validation, e.g. `num.replace(/\s/g,'');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
http://webwoman.biz/articles/Forms/NetscapeLibrary/ccnums.html

Comment: Actually, we are using Jquery. but we are not focusing on the Credit Card types like Amex, Citibank, etc. etc. At the moment we are just focus on the validation with White spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular expression to accomplish this task. take a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)

and this short [description](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) of how to use regex in JavaScript